# LLVM 2.0 can't build for iPhone simulator. GCC 4.2 works fine

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, llvm, xcode4

When I build my project (any project, really - I tried creating a new empty project with the same results), it builds fine with GCC 4.2 under either Xcode4 or Xcode 3.2.4.

If I build using LLVM 2.0 under Xcode4 or with LLVM 1.5 under Xcode3, I get compile-time build failures, but *only* when building for the Simulator.

The build errors that I get under LLVM are all in headers over which I have no control, such as UIView.h, UIDevice.h, UIApplication.h, UITextView.h and UIWebView.h in UIKit and CGPDFContext.h in CoreGraphics.

*Here's an example error, in WebView.h:*

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);   //<--- Unknown type 'UIDataDetectorTypes'
```

when UIDataDetectorTypes is indeed declared in UIDataDetectors.h which is included in that file.

*sniff*

Comment: Adam, good call on the Xcode4 tag.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be a bug in Xcode 3.2.4 or the SDK configuration.

Try placing a line like one of these in your Build Settings Preprocessor Macros:

```
-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100
```

or

```
-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=030103
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem I just had after downloading xcode 3.2.4

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too, but I had to remove the -D in Xcode, so it was just __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your installation is borked.

When you installed Xcode4 did you make sure to install it to a completely separate directory to your existing Xcode install?

It could also have something to do with your include paths or something in that vein. I'm not too sure how to go about fixing that.

I would suggest backing up any custom templates etc. and running the uninstall script for both Xcode 3.x and 4, and then reinstalling to see if that fixes the issues.

Comment: Xcode4 forces you to install to a separate directory.  I'll go ahead and try uninstalling both and let you know what I find out.

Comment: Mmmmnope.  No dice.  Just realized that it's a new problem since Xcode 3.2.4.  Guess I'll have to stick with on-device testing until I get a chance to get it better figured out.  Once I do, I'll post here.  At least it's the Simulator that's not working and not the device!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure then. Sorry :(. Good luck in figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue persist with XCode 3.2.5?

Just curious since I haven't downloaded it yet.

Comment: No, this issue is no longer present for me in Xcode 3.2.5, which uses LLVM 1.6.