# Base SDK missing for PhoneGap-based iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I have installed the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) library for iOS and created a new project, but when I run the application I get the error `Base SDK missing`. Why is this?

### edit 1

230 errors after applying mAc reply these are some of the errors:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23: error: expected function body after function declarator


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:91 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:91: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256:86 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256:86: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:258:114 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:258:114: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:187:31 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:187:31: error: unknown type name 'UIApplicationState'


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:190:4 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:190:4: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:191:28 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:191:28: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:202:45 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:202:45: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:206:4 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:206:4: error: expected a type


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITextView.h:82:22 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITextView.h:82:22: error: unknown type name 'UIDataDetectorTypes'


/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIWebView.h:54:22 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIWebView.h:54:22: error: unknown type name 'UIDataDetectorTypes'


/Users/Ahmed/Documents/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Camera.h:56:10 /Users/Ahmed/Documents/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Camera.h:56:10: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'UIPopoverControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UITabBarControllerDelegate'?


/Users/Ahmed/Documents/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Camera.m:24:3 /Users/Ahmed/Documents/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Camera.m:24:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone'; did you mean 'UIUserInterfaceIdiom'?
```

Comment: Any which base SDK are you building against? Which are available on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have import a project...

see select your project and go its INFO -> there in build Tab -> Architectures -> In Base SDK select Latest iOS -> save n close. Now select the simulator (by default Device is selected).
And then run the app.

**Edited :-**

Might be a bug in Xcode 3.2.4 or the SDK configuration.

Try placing a line like one of these in your Build Settings Preprocessor Macros:

```
-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100
```

or

```
-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=030103
```

You can [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636895/llvm-2-0-cant-build-for-iphone-simulator-gcc-4-2-works-fine) also regarding your problem.

Hope it Helps :) Adios

Comment: It may be Beacuse u r using LLVM 2.0.    LLVM 2.0 can't build for iPhone simulator. GCC 4.2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the project.pbxproj file, I had to change this in a few places:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 5.0;
```

to

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.1;
```